# How do roads switch from driving on the left side of the road to driving on the right?

Tags: usability

Some countries that drive on the left side of the road aren't island countries (although most are; the most notable exception is India). For those countries, how do people laying out roads for drivers deal with switching the side of the road that they drive on? I imagine expecting drivers to simply cross over the middle of the road might cause problems.

Comment: This is easily answered via google: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-_and_left-hand_traffic#Changing_sides_at_borders

Comment: Voting to close this because as per the [faq] *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."* This question isn't based on a problem you currently have, and there are loads of different solutions of this, as pointed out by DA01. However, if you have a question specifically about how to get people to switch lanes *in one specific case* (such as on the border between X and Y country) then that's slightly more on-topic.

Comment: @DA01 I had found those myself; I thought the question might be good to put here. Seems like it wasn't.

Answer (score 6):

## In high traffic areas, it is usually done with with bridges that cross over and swap the sides.

This is the Lotus bridge in Macau
[image]

This is the proposed Pearl River Necklace bridge, which perhaps illustrates the concept the best.

[image]

## Medium traffic areas are usually done with an intersection that may include traffic lights.

This is the traffic light crossing at the Thai-Lao Friendship Bridge.
[image]

## Very low traffic areas are usually done with signs only.

This is a sign post on the Karakoram Highway over Khunjerab Pass between China and Pakistan

[image]

Comment: Firstly, this bridge is just a concept so doesn't actually exist. Secondly, this would be an extraordinarily expensive method to use, so all but the most wealthy countries would do so. *some* countries do use bridges, yes, but this isn't 'the way' it's done, its just one of many ways.

Comment: Down-voted due to using sci-fi for evidence.

Comment: @JonW Brigdes are used for high traffic areas, even in poorer places like between Brazil and Guyana.  And the image I initially had was the best illustration of how it could be achieved.  I have added other illustrations for you now.